# How to fix issues with rigging in Blender 2.79

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

[image: Bones_Controlling_Unconnected_Mesh]

Hi there all, been tooling around with this for two days... Honestly went through dozens of videos, forums posts, and document/articles about rigging in Blender 2.79. So far I have:

- Deleted my original armature and created a new armature from scratch.
- Fiddled with parenting properties
- Joined my segmented mesh into a single solid object
- Re-reparented mesh with armature (making sure mesh was child)
- Deleted original mesh and reimported original pre-joined mesh and rejoined it, and then re-re-reparented the mesh to a clean armature
- Fiddled with different parenting options
- Fiddled with weight painting
- Reduced all weight paint to 0 with mesh and armature selected
- Used clean option in weight paint
- I've selected each bone individually and then weight painted over the whole mesh using subtract until everything was solid dark blue... a couple times
- A few other things I cannot recall everything now...

Still, what is occurring in the image, continues to occur. There are several points on the mesh where things like this are happening. I am getting areas influenced by bones that should not be (I.E. finger tips obviously connected to the pelvic/leg bone and pants connected to the wrist bone, shoe sole connected to the non-existent ground, hat brim connected to chest or neck, etc.), and some things seem to be influenced by something not even present.

I am assuming that some internal vertices were included in the automatic weight assignment when parenting the armature, but I am unsure about that, since I have removed all connected values, and reconnected them clean, but it is still occurring. I have also tried parenting without weight assignments and the exact thing is occurring in the exact places. Not sure what the deal is. I am assuming that duplicating then deleting the mesh and armature then re-parenting them would clear previously assigned conflicts, am I correct in this logic?

I'm not new to Blender 2.X or 3D modelling at all (I have about 10-12 years in the field as a hobbyist, but have produced some professional work), but recently updated to 2.8 and then dialed it back to 2.79 since 2.8 seemed funky in it's controls and where everything was hidden. However, I keep ending up with little quirks like this whenever I do custom work anymore. Usually I find my own workaround or some post on the interwebs that fixes my dilemma. However, with this issue I've come up empty on everything I've tried.

Any/all help/ideas will be immensely appreciated...

Using v2.79, on a CyberPower Fang III Black Mamba with Windows 10 64bit, Asus Cerberus GeForce 1050Ti, using Nvidia Cuda Drivers, and Blender Cycles plugin. (just in case the conflict lies in any of that)

Comment: NOTE: Also saved, deleted the scene, opened a new scene, imported the mesh and armature separately. Parented choosing "Armature Deform" then entered weight paint with mesh object selected and went into the "Weights" menu and selected "Assign Automatic from Bones." No changes... Same exact problem exists in the same exact locations...

Comment: could you please share your file, at least the part with the problem?